# How do I print a string with a printer?

Tags: c#, .net, string, printing, gdi+

I'm writing an application that need to print some information that would came from a DataGridView, I already have the string I'd like to print, I just don't know how. I found some stuff on the web that said I'd need to use a PrintDocument object and a PrintDialog.

Lets suppose I have 3 strings and I want to print to each one in one line (line 1, 2 and 3),but the first must be in bold and using the Arial font.
The output (on the paper) would be:

```
string 1 (in bold and using the Arial font)

string 2

string 3
```

**EDIT: (asked by [abelenky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34824/abelenky))**

The Code:

```
    private void PrintCoupon()
    {
        string text = "Coupon\n";

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGridViewCarrinho.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvCell in dgvRow.Cells)
            {
                text += dgvCell.Value.ToString() + "  ";
            }

            text += "\n";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(text);
        // I should print the coupon here
    }
```

So how do I do that using C#?

Thanks.

Comment: @abelenky there is the code, the complete source code is above 390 lines. But that is the part I would print the string.

Comment: yes you're right , you need to use the printdocument and I explained how in my answer , have you tried it ?

Comment: @Mehran I'm testing it now.

Comment: Are you still testing ? :)

Comment: @Mehran sorry I forgot to mark you answer, but now it's marked. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for printing strings on a paper you should draw them first on a `PrintDocument` using GDI+ in c#

in a `Winform` add `PrintDocument` tool to your project , and double click on it to access the `PrintPage` event handler of it ,
assuming you already have `s1`,`s2` and `s3` as String Variables  ,
in the `PrintPage` event handler we use :

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    Font f2 = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    Font f3 = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s1, f1, Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 10));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s2, f2, Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 40));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s3, f3, Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 60));
}
```

and whenever you wanted to print the document :

```
printDocument1.Print();
```

you may also consider using a `PrintPreviewDialog` to see what's going on before printing the document

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
using System.Drawing;

private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler
            (this.pd_PrintPage); 
pd.Print();
}

// The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed.
void pd_PrintPage(Object* /*sender*/, PrintPageEventArgs* ev) 
{
Font myFont = new Font( "m_svoboda", 14, FontStyle.Underline, GraphicsUnit.Point );

float lineHeight = myFont.GetHeight( e.Graphics ) + 4;

float yLineTop = e.MarginBounds.Top;

string text = "Coupon\n";

foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGridViewCarrinho.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvCell in dgvRow.Cells)
        {
            text += dgvCell.Value.ToString() + "  ";
        }

        text += "\n";
    }

    //MessageBox.Show(text);
    // I should print the coupon here
    e.Graphics.DrawString( text, myFont, Brushes.Black,
    new PointF( e.MarginBounds.Left, yLineTop ) );

    yLineTop += lineHeight;

}
```